# How to create html comments to wrap the custom taghelper c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm in need to wrap my custom tag helper by HTML comments. I have tried the below code example but it rendered as a string in browser.

```
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
   output.TagName = "div";
   output.PreElement.SetHtmlContent(new HtmlString("/*<!--*/\n"));
   output.PreElement.SetHtmlContent(new HtmlString("\n/*-->*/"));
   output.Content.SetHtmlContent("HI");
}
```

Does anyone provide a solution for this issue guys?? Is there any way to create HTML comment using tagbuilder()??

Actual result:

```
"/*"
<!--*/\n<div>HI</div>\n/*-->
"*/"
```

Expected result

```
/*<!--*/
<div>HI</div>
/*-->*/
```